# user permission in open cart

Tags: opencart, user-permissions

I have downloaded the open cart point of sale module. I am able to install it in my application, but unable to open the module due to a user permission issue. I am logged in with super admin role, but still unable to use it.

For which file and where in code do I need to make modifications required to allow permission to all users who access module? **Or** from where code snippet will be removed so that it will allow all users to use it.

Comment: The best way to get a quick reply is by writing an understandable post, not by stating that things are urgent. Your's did not even include a question (as  a sentence with a question mark). The last sentence I still don't completely understand, so I only replaced the shouting with bold markup. Please edit your post to make it clear (and have a someone else (preferably a native speaker of English) review it.

Comment: If you doesn't understand please do not answer. Rather than diverting discussion to some where else. The one who understand it will provide solution Thanks.

Comment: Just trying to help you learning how to get the most out of this site and at the same increase the quality of the posts. I only got to review your post because 3 people triaged it as needing improvement, which I provided. We are looking for good questions on [so] not something cryptic, because of bad grammar or other unclarities, only a few people understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable access to user group

So login to admin panel and go to `system/user/usergroup`
Edit the administrator, select all route and hit save.

You can refer  http://goo.gl/MBpxFD for more detail

Comment: Already tried this. But i need to modify it from code level. To allow all users or always return true when check for permission.